# Prepend to input field in form-group for bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap form using the following attributes:

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recipient-email" class="col-form-label">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="info@traxr.net" class="form-control" id="email">
                        </div>

....
```

I have an additional input field, where I Want to add a `https://` prefix.

Apparently, it HAS to be wrapped in an `input-group` div, which messes up the width of the input field as well as the error label is now placed on the same line

Is there a way just to add the prefix to the input field while still keeping all the code in a `form-group` container?

[image: Email vs domain input field for reference.]

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap by default provide component for same that is input group.Here you can find more https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/input-group/

And answer to your question.

```
 <div class="input-group mb-3">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
     <span class="input-group-text" id="basic- addon3">https://</span>
  </div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
</div>
```